# PySpark: LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS is getting slower in iteration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, logistic-regression

I have an iteration which calls LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS x times.

The problem is, that the iteration is getting slower every loop and finally hangs forever.

I tried a lot of different approaches, but no luck so far.

The code looks like that:

```
def getBootsrapedAttribution( iNumberOfSamples, df):

    def parsePoint(line):
        return LabeledPoint(line[2], line[3:])

    aResults = {}
    while x <= iNumberOfSamples:
        print ("## Sample: " + str(x))
        a = datetime.datetime.now()
        dfSample = sampleData(df)
        dfSample.repartition(700)
        parsedData = dfSample.rdd.map(parsePoint)
        parsedData = parsedData.repartition(700)
        parsedData.persist()
        model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(parsedData)
        parsedData.unpersist()
        b = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(b-a)
        x+=1

def sampleData(df):
    df = df.repartition(500)
    dfFalse = df.filter('col == 0').sample(False, 0.00035)
    dfTrue = df.filter('col == 1')
    dfSample = dfTrue.unionAll(dfFalse)
    return dfSample


getBootsrapedAttribution(50, df)
```

And the Output looks like this:

```
## Sample: 1
0:00:44.393886

## Sample: 2
0:00:28.403687

## Sample: 3
0:00:30.884087

## Sample: 4
0:00:33.523481

## Sample: 5
0:00:36.107836

## Sample: 6
0:00:37.077169

## Sample: 7
0:00:41.160941

## Sample: 8
0:00:54.768870

## Sample: 9
0:01:01.31139

## Sample: 10
0:00:59.326750

## Sample: 11
0:01:37.222967

## Sample: 12

...hangs forever
```

Without `model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(parsedData)` it runs without performance issues.

My cluster looks like this:

```
spark.default.parallelism   500
spark.driver.maxResultSize  20G
spark.driver.memory 200G
spark.executor.cores    32
spark.executor.instances    2
spark.executor.memory   124G
```

Does anyone know this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

The Problem is within the method `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`. Replacing this method with `LogisticRegression` in `Spark 2.1+` resolved the issue. There is no more slowing down per iteration.

Furthermore there are some more improvements you could do with the code above.
The `rdd` method `sample` can be replaced with the `DataFrame` method `sampleBy`. This will also avoid the unnecessary `union`:

`.sampleBy('col', fractions={0: 0.00035, 1: 1}, seed=1234)`

Furthermore all the `repartitions` in the code above are unnecessary. Important is that `df` passed to `getBootsrapedAttribution()` is partioned well and `cached`.